# Next.js/React warning when generating random values in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm building a next.js app that generates some random numbers which generates the warning:

> Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "1" Client: "2"

I think I understand why I get this warning (the virtual DOM is kinda-sorta-out-of-sync with what was sent from the server). I'm just wondering if there's a way to let next.js/React know that this is ok in this situation. Or is there a way to only generate the random on the server and let the client use this as a literal?

Or should I just ignore the warning?

Comment: In which context/method are you creating the random values?

Comment: @FabianSchultz The component constructor.

Comment: also have the same problem - have 'generated' value for link (it's intended), but can't find any solution to remove that warning from my console

Comment: for nextjs questions, i'd recommend going to spectrum.chat and asking there, as a lot of the developers on there use next.js

Comment: @Koen Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @Cully Sadly, no.

Comment: @Koen Thanks for the reply. I kinda found a workaround. Not ideal, but no more warning at least. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59976790/1526406

Answer (score 12):

Moving JavaScript random variable into React state solved the problem for me.

Here's my problem (simplified) before:

```
function RandomNumber() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  return <p>{randomNumber}</p>;
}
```

After

```
function RandomNumber() {
  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRandomNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
  }, []);

  return <p>{randomNumber}</p>;
}
```

My code used React Hooks `useState` and `useEffect`, but previous React lifecycle methods `setState` and `componentDidMount` should work fine too

Comment: The problem with this solution seems to be that on initial render it will be undefined, which defeats the purpose of server-side pre-rendering

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is that you wrap the content that you have some random generated content in, inside a  component.

`components/NoSsr.js`

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import React from 'react';

const NoSsr = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(NoSsr), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

And then in your file:

```
<NoSsr>
    { Math.random() }
</NoSsr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with `useMemo`:

```
 const randomNumber = useMemo(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), []);
```

Comment: I'm doing this multiple times in a row on the server. I guess this code would give me the same number each time?

Comment: Depends on what you write in the dependency array. You can create an array of random numbers that gets updated ones your rows state update.

Comment: This does not solve the hydration issue. The problem is not memoization, it's the fact that the content pre-generated on the server does not match the content generated during hydration on the client-side. Forcing the random number to only be generated on the client is the solution (like the other answers mentioned).

Comment: I have similar problem with Array random, I tried memoizing, but that doesn't work for server. When I consoled inside memo with no deps, it consoled 4 times on server for me. Which is strange, as it shouldn't happen.